# WPA2 Enterprise with NPS and WLC

Tags: cisco, ieee-802.11, radius, cisco-wlc

I am pretty new to this and am trying to set up WPA2 enterprise where users can connect to the Wifi using their AD credentials (PEAP-MSCHAPv2).

The Cisco WLC has been configured to relay requests to the NPS, which is also the DC.  The NPS can be pinged from the WLC and vice-versa.  Passwords have been checked and doubled checked and are correctly entered in the WLC and in the NPS for the radius client.

When trying to connect to the WiFi, test is user is prompted for their credentials, which is what we want.  Creds are entered and we get the message that it was not able to connect.

Checking event viewer of the NPS (also the DC), I see the following errors:

- Under **Network Policy and Access Services**:

  [image]
- Under **Windows Logs** -> **Application**:

  [image]
- Under **Windows Log** -> **System**:

  [image]

From what I have found online, reason 22 comes up when there is an issue with the cert.  On the client side, I have disabled the need to validate certs (for testing purposes).  I have added a cert from our CA (on a different DC) to the NPS as shown below:

[image]

Not sure why users are not able to connect or how to fix the error.  Any suggestions or ideas are appreciated!

Edit - adding client config:

[image]

Not validating certs:

[image]

Also, from client, shows that EAP type 25 is being sent from Client:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the settings of the NPS Network Policy "Conditions" tab? In my setup it is setup with: Authenticaiton type = EAP / Nas Port Type = Wireless IEEE 802.11 / Windows Group = <my group of authorized users>

Comment: @JFL i have two conditions under my network policy:  

Nas Port Type = Wireless - Other or Wireless - IEEE 802.11 
Windows Groups = domain/Users

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

PEAP-MSCHAPv2 does need to to validate server side certificate. I see you have disabled the need to validate certs (for testing purposes). It wont work without validating server side cert.

This looks like mis-configuration issue. You need to make sure same authentication type is used at both ends (client and server). Wireless profiles at client must be configured to use/support PEAP-MSCHAPv2. If you see your first screen shot, i dont see any value in front of 'EAP Type:' field. And in your last screen shot, select checkbox against MS-CHAPv2.

Comment: I found one [link](http://community.arubanetworks.com/t5/Wireless-Access/802-1x-Authentication-with-Microsoft-NPS/td-p/203079). showing same behavior you seeing.

Comment: Validation of the cert is not required. That is a client side configuration, although this will make the connection significantly less secure.

Comment: @Vinnie - I made the changes to Network Policy to accept the MS-CHAPv2 authentication method and this came up in the logs: 

Reason Code:  66
Reason: The user attempted to use an authentication method that is not enabled on the matching network policy.

Also, I have edited the original post to include my current client side configuration.

Comment: @ArturoMartinez its difficult to know the root cause here, because we don't know inside-out information about network details at your end. But log does say that end client and server are not talking same authentication protocol.